How to generate random numbers that roughly follow a normal distribution that also add up to a specific total?
I'm trying to generate a random set of numbers that add up to a specific total, and a specific maximum value that the numbers can reach.
However each approach I seem to have come across have some flaw that makes it unusable.

Sometimes the results don't add up to the correct total.

Sometimes the random generation results in the same numbers every time.

Some functions result in too many iterations.


I'm beginning to think this is somewhat mathematically impossible? I'm wondering if anyone can help me work out the code to do this.
The numbers should follow these rules:

The numbers must add up to variable t.

The minimum value of a generated number is 1.

The maximum value should be variable m.

The generated numbers must follow as close to a normal distribution as is feasible.

The normal distribution must be centered on 1.

The normal distribution should be flat enough to almost get examples of each number up to the maximum.

All the numbers must be integers.


An example is, if t is 30, and m is 5, then the result would be:
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5
Another result might be:
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5
Here is a function I have for this, but this uses a while loop which I would prefer to avoid, as it often results in too many iterations.
public static List<int> GenerateNumbers(int t, int m)
{
    double mean = 1.0;
    double variance = 10.0;
    double[] probabilities = new double[m];
    double sumProbabilities = 0.0;
 
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        double exponent = -Math.Pow(i - mean, 2) / (2 * variance);
        probabilities[i - 1] = Math.Exp(exponent);
        sumProbabilities += probabilities[i - 1];
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        probabilities[i] /= sumProbabilities;
    }
 
    double meanValue = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        meanValue += probabilities[i] * (i + 1);
    }
    int N = (int)Math.Round(t / meanValue);
 
    int[] frequencies = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        frequencies[i] = (int)Math.Round(probabilities[i] * N);
    }
 
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (frequencies[i] > frequencies[i - 1])
        {
            frequencies[i] = frequencies[i - 1];
        }
    }
 
    int currentSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        currentSum += frequencies[i] * (i + 1);
    }
 
    int maxIterations = 25000;
    int iterationCount = 0;
 
    while (currentSum != t && iterationCount < maxIterations)
    {
        iterationCount++;
        if (currentSum < t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                if (frequencies[i] < (i == 0 ? frequencies[0] : frequencies[i - 1]))
                {
                    frequencies[i]++;
                    currentSum += (i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (frequencies[i] > 0)
                {
                    frequencies[i]--;
                    currentSum -= (i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    if (iterationCount >= maxIterations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to adjust frequencies to match t within max iterations.");
    }
 
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < frequencies[i]; j++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }
 
    System.Random rand = new System.Random();
    numbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToList();
 
    return numbers;
}

How can I go about this?

If all the numbers are integers, it is not a normal distribution. Pick the right model, otherwise you're twisting yourself into a pretzel.

@pjs That's why I said roughly follow a normal distribution. I don't intend on making this exact, I know that would be impossible.

The normal distribution is continuous, has infinite support, and is symmetric about its mean. You want both the mean and the minimum to be 1, and a fixed upper bound. Your requirements are impossible to achieve if you assume the normal as a starting point, and mathematically impossible regardless since the mean cannot equal the minimum unless the min and max are the same value. Pick a suitable bounded skewed discrete distribution.

@pjs Alright, but that would be considered semantics really. I can call it a half-normal distribution if that is clearer, but that doesn't really change results of the question.

@ConnorMoran, if you want a normal distribution that's not necessarily random, then it might prove valuable to elaborate on the use case for what you're trying to achieve and we can provide better insight on possible solutions for you.

Interesting question, but I think you'll get a more suitable audience at math.stackexchange.com since it's mostly conceptual. That said, one approach is to enumerate integer partitions of the target value t and then score each partition according to how well it fits the criteria, and then just take the partition which has the best score. The number of partitions to be considered is a function of t and might grow pretty fast, so you might need some heuristics to limit the number of partitions that need to be considered. A web search for "integer partitions" will find some resources.

"Digits" and arbitrary limits means not all solutions are feasible; and no amount of dynamic programming will fix it. "Generating" and then scaling (down or up) is the only "practical" solution; that's how "sharing" works.

Even ignoring the weirdness of having the minimum and mean both being 1, that's a weird set of specs (for example, getting all the data to sum to a specified number is very limiting). What is the origin/rationale for these specs?

Quite tricky because of the constraints but can try this:

Decide how many numbers you need. Let's call this N. You might
estimate N by dividing t by the average value you expect.
Generate N random numbers from a normal distribution centered at 1.
Clip the numbers so they are at least 1 and at most m. This means if
a number is less than 1, set it to 1; if it's more than m, set it to
m.
Adjust the numbers to sum up to t:

Round the numbers to integers.
Calculate the difference between t and the sum of your numbers.
If the sum is less than t, add 1 to some of the numbers (preferably ones less than m) until the total matches t.
If the sum is more than t, subtract 1 from some numbers (ones greater than 1) until the total matches t.
public static List<int> GenerateNumbers(int t, int m)
{
    double mean = 1.0;
    double stdDev = 1.0;
    int N = (int)Math.Round(t / mean);

    List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        double num = NextGaussian(rand, mean, stdDev);
        if (num < 1) num = 1;
        if (num > m) num = m;
        numbers.Add(num);
    }

    List<int> intNumbers = numbers.Select(x => (int)Math.Round(x)).ToList();
    int currentSum = intNumbers.Sum();
    int iterationCount = 0;
    int maxIterations = 10000;

    while (currentSum != t && iterationCount < maxIterations)
    {
        iterationCount++;
        if (currentSum < t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < intNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (intNumbers[i] < m)
                {
                    intNumbers[i]++;
                    currentSum++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (currentSum > t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < intNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (intNumbers[i] > 1)
                {
                    intNumbers[i]--;
                    currentSum--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (iterationCount >= maxIterations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to adjust numbers to match t within max iterations.");
    }

    intNumbers = intNumbers.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToList();
    return intNumbers;
}

public static double NextGaussian(Random rand, double mean, double stdDev)
{
    double u1 = rand.NextDouble();
    double u2 = rand.NextDouble();
    double randStdNormal = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) * Math.Cos(2.0 * Math.PI * u2);
    double randNormal = mean + stdDev * randStdNormal;
    return randNormal;
}


This gives me 30 1s I'm afraid!

Apologies in advance. I don't use C# so the code provided below is in Ruby, which essentially reads like pseudocode that can actually run. I've tried to comment liberally as well. Hopefully it will be easy for you to migrate to your preferred language.
As I mentioned in comments on the original question, I think it's a bad idea to try to tie this to the normal distribution. Reiterating those points, the normal:

is continuous;
has infinite support; and
is symmetric about its mean.

Meanwhile, your specs for the generated data include:

outcomes are all integers, i.e., it should actually be a discrete distribution;
it should have a lower bound of 1 and a specified (and relatively small) upper bound m; and
the mean and the minimum should be 1.

That last requirement is mathematically impossible. The mean of a distribution is a convex combination of all the possible values, and thus cannot be equal to either end of the range unless the length of the range is zero.
Since I think the normal distribution is a bad starting point, I've chosen to ignore it and go straight for what I considered a reasonable discrete distribution that's easy to generate. I opted for a shifted binomial distribution. An even easier alternative would be a discrete uniform distribution, but the binomial is "normal-like" to the extent that it has a unimodal peak near its mean. The standard binomial counts the number of successes obtained from performing n independent Bernoulli trials, each having probability p of yielding a success, so it produces values X such that 0 ≤ X ≤ n. We can then shift this to an arbitrary range min ≤ X ≤ max by setting n = max - min and adding min to the resulting X. The following function implements the logic just described:
# Generate binomially distributed outcomes that fall between
# *min* and *max*, inclusive. The argument *prob* is the Bernoulli
# probability of incrementing the total on each Bernoulli trial.
# If you don't override the default value of 0 for *min*, this
# generates unshifted binomials.

def shifted_binomial(min: 0, max:, prob:)
  fail "invalid min/max values" if min > max
  fail "invalid argument for prob" unless (0.0..1.0).include?(prob)
  range = max - min
  sum = 0
  range.times { sum += 1 if rand <= prob }  # rand generates a U(0,1)
  return sum + min
end

We can use that method to generate outcomes in the range 1 to max (your m) that sum to total. The value of total gets decremented by each value generated, driving it towards 0. To avoid driving it beyond 0, we set the binomial's max to the minimum of max and the amount by which we're currently short of the target total. That means the last value generated actually has a different distribution than the other binomials, even though it's within the specified range. This may or may not be a concern for you, but in case it is I've mixed it in amongst the others by shuffling:
def generate_target_sum(total:, max:, prob:)
  values = []   # start with an empty array for generated values
  while total > 0
    # Spec said range start is always 1, so hardwiring that.
    # Generating up to the minimum of *max* and *total* guarantees
    # that we won't exceed the target total.
    candidate = shifted_binomial(min: 1, max: [max, total].min, prob:)
    values << candidate  # append the new value to the array, and...
    total -= candidate   # ...decrement its value from the running tally
  end
  # Shufflling masks the fact that the conditional distribution
  # of the last outcome is different from the other outcomes.
  return values.shuffle
end

The last part is to call the previous method and report the results. I've chosen to do so using different p-values for the underlying binomial/Bernoulli distributions. This demos the usage, but also shows how the p-value affects the propensity to generate smaller or larger values.
for p_val in [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8] do
  # Generate an array of outcome values having the specified range and total.
  # Larger values of *prob* will yield larger individual values on average,
  # while smaller *prob* yields more small values (and hence more outcomes to
  # achieve the target total).
  outcome = generate_target_sum(total: 30, max: 5, prob: p_val)
  puts "For p = #{p_val}: outcome = #{outcome.inspect}, sum = #{outcome.sum}"
end

Sample output from a run of this:
For p = 0.2: outcome = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1], sum = 30
For p = 0.4: outcome = [4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2], sum = 30
For p = 0.6: outcome = [3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4], sum = 30
For p = 0.8: outcome = [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5], sum = 30

Note that all runs yield the target sum. Runs with smaller p-values have a greater propensity for smaller values, and thus are prone to need more values to get to the target sum. Larger p-values result in a smaller number of larger values. Since the results are randomly generated, your results will vary if you re-run the provided code or reimplement it.

Thank you, Maybe I just suck at using the right terminology.
The reason I asked for a normal distribution is I need more lower values than higher ones. For example, there should always be more 1s than 2s, more 2s than 3s and so on.
Is that even possible or?

@ConnorMoran If you review the last section of my post, you’ll see that using a low p-value does what you’ve asked for. You can play with it to dial it in to something you like.

@ConnorMoran If you think the binomial drops off too quickly when you use low p-values, another alternative would be to switch distributions. One possibility would be a right skewed discrete triangle distribution: ceiling(m * (1 .0 - sqrt(rand))).  That would give you a linear drop off.

Thank you so much! I did see the part of using lower p-values but I didn't want so many 1s. It's hard to balance. Perhaps I need a steep exponential. Apologies for being standoffish. It's something I've seen struggling with for a few weeks. This is to be used to group sets for a gameplay mechanic so it's quite specific.
